# How to create multiple tasks in one jar(Spring Cloud Task)?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Use case(Spring cloud task):

I have different tasks which are independent of each other. I want to create those tasks in one jar and trigger task from command line. Is it possible ?

Also I want to schedule them using crontab. Please suggest.

Comment: Currently, are all the tasks in separate jars/modules?

Comment: No, its new development.

Comment: I had a similar use case. I have defined multiple jobs in my jar. I treat each of them as a different task. I use --spring.batch.job.names while starting up the jar to decide which job/task to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would need to have all those independent tasks inside the same jar but as long as you have a way to invoke the appropriate task based on your criteria, you could use Spring Cloud Data Flow to set this up.

- You register your single jar with all the independent tasks as a task application (let's say mytask)
- You create a schedule to trigger this task with the command line arguments to specify the criteria to launch the appropriate functionality inside the task jar
  (Note that the scheduler support is only available on Kubernetes and Cloud Foundry)
- Depending on the context you might want to consider using `composed tasks` as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks

Comment: How can we schedule wala crontab and trigger task ?

Comment: SCDF provides a scheduler in its UI. After creating a task you can schedule the task. Also, for triggering a task you can use the REST APIs provided by SCDF or Spring Cloud Dataflow Shell. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-schedule-launch-tasks
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-launch